# Updating an UILabel looks like wasting performances

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, memory-management, uilabel

I'm working on a project, where i have to update the text of a UILabel really regularly (0.085f). So, I insert the update of the label in a loop like this :

```
MetresNumber = MetresNumber + 0.25;
DisplayMetres.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%07.0f", MetresNumber];
```

I precise that "MetresNumber" is a float, and "DisplayMetres" the UILabel.

And this sort of code really really makes bad performances ! It's incredible how slower it goes since i've added those lines.

I made some searches, and found elements like :

```
[DisplayMetres setNeedsDisplay];
```

But it didn't change and update the text on the label.

It's in a loop called with :

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.085 target:self selector:@selector(myLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

So my question is, could my code be improve, to get better performances, or should i forget my UILabel because it's too slow with ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you please define 'really regularly'?

Comment: I don't know.  You have explained the types of those variables.  But you don't explain how they are used.

Comment: 0.085f, i've edited. They are just use in a loop, and MetresNumber is increment while i don't stop the loop. I just want to set the text up but here it's too slow in the run. (I've edited my post)

Comment: Doesn't run at the speed you want? Takes a lot of processor? Done some profiling?

Comment: The speed is correct, because the loop is doing some other things which need this timing. But it takes a lot of processor when i add this two lines in my code, and it gaves me some lags. So i don't know how to reduce those lags from those two lines :/

Comment: What i'm looking for is eventually a function, which refresh the content of the label, whithout needs to call [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%07.0f", MetresNumber]; ...

Comment: Using a function could make a difference?

Comment: I don't think that you can improve the performance of updating the label, but you could do it less often.  Maybe once every half second would be often enough (every 5-6 times through the loop)?

Comment: Possible that it could improve do it less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (void)setNeedsLayout

Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews. This method makes a note of the request and returns immediately. Because this method does not force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update cycle, you can use it to invalidate the layout of multiple views before any of those views are updated. This behavior allows you to consolidate all of your layout updates to one update cycle, which is usually better for performance.

Another problem is that a scheduledTimer will not get called while the main thread is tracking touches. You need to schedule the timer in the main run loop.

So instead of doing

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

use

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Also Use Timer selector method like below:

```
- (void) updateLabel:(id) sender {
    MetresNumber = MetresNumber + 0.25;
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%07.0f", MetresNumber];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        DisplayMetres.text = text;
    });
```

}

Comment: I'm going to try your solution, i will keep you informed ;)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any performance issues when you are just updating a single label every 85ms. First find out what actually causes the lags. Use the *Time Profiler* instrument.
I think most time will be spent on the string drawing.

Here are some tips how you can optimize your code:

- You don't need to call `setNeedsLayout` or `setNeedsDisplay` explicitely on the label. Just set the text property (on the main thread of course).
- The resulting string in your code will always be a 7-digit integer. Consider using an integer instead of a float. Formatting an integer will be faster.
- `stringWithFormat` can be slow sometimes. You could try using a `NSNumberFormatter` or simply generate the string with: `[@(MetresNumber) stringValue]`
- In your code the string actually doesn't change everytime the timer fires. Only every 4th time. You can set the time interval to 4*0.085 and replace `MetresNumber = MetresNumber + 0.25` with `MetresNumber = MetresNumber + 1`.
- Try using [this](https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel) custom UILabel class
- Don't use UILabel at all. Use pre-drawn images for each digit.
- Schedule the timer with `NSRunLoopCommonModes` (see answer from Lightygalaxy)